# How can I add a onScroll event to iScroll4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, iscroll4

The `onScroll` event is not yet supported by the [iScroll4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4).

Is there a known way to extend the iScroll to support an `onScroll` event?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', { 
  onScrollMove: function() {
    console.log('onScrollMove');
  },
  onScrollEnd: function() {
    console.log('onScrollEnd');
  }
});
```

This is a quick example of how to register your callback functions following the advice of the earlier response to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8489043

Answer (score 4):

have a look at the source here: https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/blob/v4/src/iscroll.js#L127-L139

on lines 127-139 you'll see that you can specify a `onScrollStart` function.

Maybe you can tweak your way arround with the `onScrollStart`, `onScrollMove` and the `onScrollEnd` callbacks

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. There should be better iScroll documentation for these events!

Comment: Hoi Manuel, I don't see any version information included in the link, would the line etc. shift if the source changes?\